# Temporarily disable data binding

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a app in Android using data bindings.

A have a SeekBar which is updated automatically from the background.

```
<SeekBar
     ...
     android:progress="@{objectModel.progressValue}" />
```

It is working fine, but the problem is if I'm tracking the seekbar, and the background updates the value, mess up the tracking action.

I believe the best way is to disable the data binding temporarily, like below, but I don't know how to do that:

```
        mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            // restore the data binding

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            // temporarily disable the UI update

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO: Auto-generated method stub
        }

        });
```

If someone could explain to me how to do that, or give me some example code, that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can set a variable to true in onStartTrackingTouch and set it back to false in onStopTrackingTouch and check it before each UI update